# Getting number of days for a specific month and year between two dates SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve the number of days between two dates that overlap a specific month.

For Example :

```
Month = 1 
Year = 2020 
StartDate ='2019-11-12' 
ENDDate ='2020-1-13' 

Result = 13 days
```

13 because there are 13 days between the dates that are in the selected month:  January 2020

---

Other Example:

```
Month=9 
Year =2019
StartDate = '2019-8-13' 
ENDDate ='2020-1-1' 

Result = 30 days
```

30 because there are 30 days between the dates that are in the selected month:  September 2019

Comment: How do you get 13 days between 12 November 2019 and 13 January 2020? That's 62 days... For 13 August 2019 to 01 January 2020 there are 141 days. Your logic makes no sense.

Comment: i said that i want to retrieve the number of days for a specific month , as a parameter i should enter the number of month and in my case it's 1 for the first example than it should be 13 days as a result

Comment: Do you mean you want to count the number of days between two dates, but only in a particular month; such that selecting 1 meant you only counted the days between the two dates that are actually in January?

Comment: January has 31 days, not 13. Explain what you're after here, it is completely unclear.

Comment: Yes i  want to count the number of days between two dates, but only in a particular month; such that selecting 1 meant you only counted the days between the two dates but just in the month January

Comment: @zbee   i have as parametere Month and Year so in that case in january between those two dates i have 13 days as this example  Month = 1 Year = 2020 StartDate ='2019-11-12' ENDDate ='2020-1-13' Result = 13 days

Comment: Please add  more examples, your request is totally unclear

Comment: Parameter : Month = 2 , Year = 2020 , Startdate ='2020-1-12', EndDate='2020-2-24'       Result = 24                                                                                                                          Parameter : Month = 3 ,Year = 2019 , StartDate ='2020-2-1', EndDate='2020-3-25'       Result = 0

Comment: Here's My case : i have contracts wich have StartDate and Date and for fiscal calculation i should calculate revenu per month for all my contracts so i should determine how many days that contract is active in the specific month , and as my calculations depend on fiscal year i should use the year also as a parameter ==> so i should get the number of active days for contract for the specific month and specific year as shown in examples

Comment: All this information should be in your **question** @WaelArbi , not the comments.

Comment: sorry this is my second post here.. thank you for understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic formula for the number of overlapping days in two ranges is

```
MAX(MIN(end1, end2) - MAX(start1, start2) + 1, 0)
```

In your case you have one set of Start and End dates, you must construct the other from the given month and year using `datefromparts` and `eomonth`.

Unfortunately SQL Server doesn't support `LEAST` and `GREATEST` formulas as do MySQL and Oracle, so this is a bit painful to implement. Here's an example using variables:

```
declare @month int;
declare @year int;
declare @startDate date;
declare @endDate date;
declare @startOfMonth date;
declare @endOfMonth date;
declare @minEnd date;
declare @maxStart date;
set @month = 1;
set @year = 2020;
set @startDate = '2019-11-12';
set @endDate = '2020-01-13';
set @startOfMonth = datefromparts(@year, @month, 1)
set @endOfMonth = eomonth(@startOfMonth)
set @minEnd = case when @endDate < @endOfMonth then @endDate
                   else @endOfMonth
              end;
set @maxStart = case when @startDate < @startOfMonth then @startOfMonth
                     else @startDate
                end;
select case when datediff(day, @maxStart, @minEnd) + 1 < 0 then 0
            else datediff(day, @maxStart, @minEnd) + 1
       end as days_in_month
```

Output:

```
13
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=edf645fce98fdfb02c99ba21b50e816a); this includes other sample date ranges.

You could implement something similar using a series of CTEs if the values are derived from a table.